# Force typescript undefined property declaration

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I have a monorepo setup with multiple frontends and a backend, all written in typescript.
There is a shared package types that defines the request and response dtos. Here is sample

Inside `types`

```js
export interface CreateBookRequest {
    title: string;
    year?: number
}
```

I can easily import this in my frontends and make sure the request is always the same.

In backend I have nestjs with class validator to check my dto so i need to do

```js
export class CreateBookRequestDto implements CreateBookRequest {
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    readonly title: string;

    @IsNumber()
    @IsOptional()
    readonly year?: number;
}
```

This works fine, I'm happy with the result

But suppose i want to add an optional property to `CreateBookRequest` like

```js
export interface CreateBookRequest {
    title: string;
    year?: number;
    author?: string;
}
```

In this case, typescript is not indicating me in any way on `CreateBookRequestDto` that there is a new property added, because it's optional. This causes problems because even if the property is optional, I still need to add it to my DTO in order for it to be validated with the proper decorators. With my configuration, non-validated properties will be stripped from the request.

Is there a way to make typescript (or event eslint) yell at me for this, or a solution on the `class-validator` side?

Comment: What issues does it cause? This feels like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). On the face of it, it's an optional property, so those implementations are valid, and there's nothing to complain about. If you want to force implementations to have the property, don't make it optional. (You could, say, make it `string | undefined`, which would make TypeScript complain about the implementations lacking the property.)

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. Your question is about TypeScript (and possibly `class-validator`?), not Nest.js or monorepos.

Comment: As @T.J.Crowder suggested, this seems like the wrong question to ask. If an object has an *optional* property, then why should you get a warning for not having it? That would describe is a *mandatory* property. If it's indeed optional thus it is allowed to not exist, *however* you need to notify other people that it exists then it's not a TypeScript problem but *project management and collaboration problem*.

Comment: The problem is that, even if optional, I still need to add it to my dto in order to be validated with the proper decorators.
With my configuration, not validated properties will be stripped from the request

Comment: @MarioRossi - Thanks for clarifying. (In the future, please use the "edit" link to add details to the question rather than a comment. I've updated the question to fold your comment into it.)

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It's a typo. I've updated the question